# Duplicate values are getting added on clicking of new button in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom

I have one button New which will open model popup window

```
<lightning-button label="New" slot="actions" onclick={openModel}></lightning-button>
```

On click of button openModel function will get call from js which ic calling loaddata function.

```
t_Fields =[];

 openModal() {
    this.loadData();
}

loadData(){
    for(var key in this.tData){
        this.t_Fields = [...this.t_Fields, {value:this.tabDetails[key], 
 label:this.tData[key]}];
    }
}
```

tData is capturing values in connectedcall back when page loads and that I need to show in one of the input box when i will click on new.

But whenever I am closing form...same values are getting added like when I am clicking on New button first time values are

```
red
Orange
Blue
```

when i am clicking on cancel or close button and again clicking on New button then values showing like and so on

```
red
Orange
Blue
red
Orange
Blue
```

and so on..

Please help, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `Spread` operator in Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

This line:  [...this.t_Fields, {value:this.tabDetails[key],
label:this.tData[key]}];

Combines existing `this.t_Fields` with new `this.t_Fields`.

So on modal close or cancel, always **reset** the value of `this.t_Fields` to `[]` and other variables in your component as applicable, until you want to retain the values.